# Getting linker error when working with Objection.h

Tags: linker

I'm currently working with Objection.h and an Open Source project called Linklyy, and I'm getting the following linker error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection.framework/Objection, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection.framework/Objection
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectFactory._injector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectFactory.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectFactory in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectFactory.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectFactory in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectFactory.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjection in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjection.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjection.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjection in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjection.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjection.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionBindingEntry._instance in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionBindingEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionBindingEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionBindingEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionEntry.injector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$___JSObjectionInjectorDefaultModule._injector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjector._globalContext in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjector._context in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjector._modules in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjector._eagerSingletons in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$___JSObjectionInjectorDefaultModule in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$___JSObjectionInjectorDefaultModule in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionInjector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionInjector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjectorEntry._lifeCycle in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjectorEntry._classEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionInjectorEntry._storageCache in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionInjectorEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionInjectorEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionInjectorEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$___JSClassProvider._class in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionModule._bindings in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionModule._eagerSingletons in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$___JSClassProvider in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$___JSClassProvider in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionModule in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionModule in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionModule.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry._provider in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry._lifeCycle in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry._storageCache in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry._block in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionProviderEntry in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionProviderEntry.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector in:
    /Users/devendrapatel/Sample-Project/Linklyy/iOS/Linklyy/Objection-iOS.framework/Objection-iOS(JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector.o)
    /Users/devendrapatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linklyy-dwuyvbeuilhglaangpauxurclyhw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(JSObjectionRuntimePropertyReflector.o)
ld: 40 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I see that the architecture should be changed based on the warning, but there is also a linker error present. Can anyone help me figure out the cause of the inker error? I'm sure that it is something related to Objection.h. Please, don't hesitate to ask for more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check targets for the `JSObjection`. It's look like the `JSObjection` included in the App target and a Pods target at the same time. It is also possible that `libJSObjection.a` is linked with the Pods and with the main App.